# Jquery replace and append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a control that let the developer only add **Input Text** with a class ... then my code should replace this input with table and append the input to the table ... but this not works as i need ...

```
<asp:textbox id="txtCalendar" class="myDatePicker" runat="server" />

JQuery: calendarInput = $(".myDatePicker");


table = $("<table>",{ Properties});

- tr = $("<tr>"); - td=$("<td>");

tr.append(td);
table.append(tr);
calendarInput.replaceWith(table);
td.append(calendarInput);
```

i Tried the clone but nothing works ... please help.

**Note: without asp.net works**

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/uP95A/ - what happens when you run the code?

Comment: removes the input text and didn't append it to the td

Comment: my code is some how complecated ... this is a small example ... it seems like my code have a small error ... i am trying now to re write it from the beginning ... if nothing done i will post it here ... thanks for your fast replay :)